# Regex help for find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++, data-munging

I have a file in notepad with this text as example:

```
*Given* I get an user ID from XXX
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "invalid_token"
*When* I send a POST request to api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"new_name"
*Then* the response code should be 401
*And* the response should contain "Invalid authorization token"

*Given* I get an user ID from XXX
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "YYY"
*When* I send a POST request to api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"new_name"
*Then* the response code should be 200
*And* the response should contain "new_name"

*Given* I get an user ID from "XXX"
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "YYY"
*When* I send a POST request to api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"folder_name"?automaticRename=true
*Then* the response code should be 200
*And* the response should contain "folder_name 1"
```

**What I need to do:** before each word **api**, i need to insert `{code:none}` and insert `{code}` at the end of the line. Example:

```
api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"folder_name"?automaticRename=true
```

would be:

```
{code:none}api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"folder_name"?automaticRename=true{code}
```

The first part is easy, I would just replace **api** for **{code:none}api** in Notepad++. The last part is my problem. Not all lines ends with the same text ... so I would need to find a regex that would Insert `{code}` at the end of the each line that it finds the word **api** somewhere, or some other approach ... Not sure if this was clear, I can try to explain better, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++ :

1. Hit Ctrl+H
2. In "Find what", type `(.*)api(.*)\r`
3. In "Replace with", type `\1api\2{code}\r`
4. Check "Search Mode > Regular expression
5. Hit "Replace All"

Comment: You're the man, it worked like a charm! I'll mark it as resolved in 5 minutes once it allows me :-)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bapi\b.*$`
- Replace with: `{code:none}$0{code}`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\bapi\b : api not preceeded or followed by word character
.*      : 0 or more any character
$       : end of line
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Replacement:**

```
{code:none} : literally
$0          : the whole match
{code}      : literally
```

**Result for given example:**

```
*Given* I get an user ID from XXX
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "invalid_token"
*When* I send a POST request to {code:none}api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"new_name"{code}
*Then* the response code should be 401
*And* the response should contain "Invalid authorization token"

*Given* I get an user ID from XXX
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "YYY"
*When* I send a POST request to {code:none}api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"new_name"{code}
*Then* the response code should be 200
*And* the response should contain "new_name"

*Given* I get an user ID from "XXX"
*And* I set header "Authorization" with value "YYY"
*When* I send a POST request to {code:none}api/endpoint/"documentlibraryID"/"identity_id"/root/"folder_name"?automaticRename=true{code}
*Then* the response code should be 200
*And* the response should contain "folder_name 1"
```